# Anaconda changes environment for python, but not ipython

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, conda

In short: How do I set the environment for iPython with conda?

```
$ which python
/usr/local/anaconda2/bin/python
$ which ipython
/usr/local/anaconda2/bin/ipython
$ source activate myenv2
discarding /usr/local/anaconda2/bin from PATH
prepending /home/username/.conda/envs/myenv2/bin to PATH
$ which python
/home/username/.conda/envs/myenv2/bin/python
$ which ipython
/usr/bin/ipython
```

Comment: are you sure that you have installed `ipython` into `myenv2`?

Comment: @cel No I have not. I thought iPython would just grab `python` from `PATH` on runtime.

Comment: conda environments are very similar to virtualenvs. They are all separated and you have to install packages separately.

Comment: You can also use `$ conda create --clone base_env --name new_env` to create a new environment containing softlinks to all the packages in `base_env`, including `ipython`

Answer (score 1):

`iPython` needs to be seperately installed for each conda environment, as via comment from @cel